# Why my complexity of bottom is not O(n^3)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, graph-algorithm

From what I learned, the complexity of bottom-up should be n^3, However, mine shows me it's almost like O(n). I have been checking these code many times but still no clue why it's not n^3 complexity. Do I miss something here?

```
/**
 * Using the bottom-up approach to fill in the table m and s for matrices P
 * @param P an array storing the matrices chain
 */
public void matrixChainOrder(int[] P){

    int n = P.length-1;
    m = new int[n+1][n+1];
    s = new int[n][n+1];
    for (int i=1; i <= n; i++ ){
        m[i][i] = 0;
    }

    for (int l = 2; l <= n; l++){
        for (int i = 1; i <= n-l + 1; i++){

            int j = i + l - 1;
            m[i][j] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

            for (int k = i; k <= j -1; k++){
                int q = m[i][k] + m[k+1][j] + P[i-1]*P[k]*P[j];
                if (q < m[i][j]){
                    m[i][j] = q;
                    s[i][j] = k;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


/**
 * Print out the optimal parenthesization of matrices chain P
 * @param s the auxiliary table storing the parenthesization
 * @param i the index of the start matrix
 * @param j the index of the end matrix
 */
public void printOptimalParens(int[][] s, int i, int j){
    if (i == j){
        System.out.print("A"+ i);
    }
    else{
        System.out.print("(");
        printOptimalParens(s, i, s[i][j]);
        printOptimalParens(s, s[i][j] + 1, j);
        System.out.print(")");
    }
}



/**
 * Compute the product of the matrices chain
 * @param A The matrices chain, it is an array of matrices
 * @param s the auxiliary table storing the parenthesization
 * @param i the start matrix
 * @param j the end matrix
 * @return the product matrix of the matrices chain
 */
public long[][] matrixChainMultiply(long[][][] A, int[][] s, int i, int j){

    if (i == j){
        return A[i];
    }
    if (i + 1 == j){

        return multiply(A[i], A[j]);
    }


    long[][] C = matrixChainMultiply(A, s, i, s[i+1][j+1]-1);
    long[][] D = matrixChainMultiply(A, s, s[i+1][j+1], j);

    return  multiply(C, D);
}


/**
 * A helper method to compute 2 matrices
 * @param X the first matrix
 * @param Y the secodn matrix
 * @return the product of these two matrices
 */
public long[][] multiply(long[][] X, long[][] Y){

    int r = X.length;
    int c = X[0].length;
    int c2 = Y[0].length;
    long[][] B = new long[r][c2];

    for (int u = 0; u < r; u++){
        for (int v = 0; v < c2; v++){
            for (int w = 0; w < c; w++){

                B[u][v] += X[u][w] * Y[w][v];                   
            }                   
        }
    }
    return B;
}
```

Comment: I think it's better if you also give explanation why you believe your algorithm is O(n).

Comment: I wrote a test driver and the result showed me it's almost like O(n)

Comment: What are the values of n (the length of the chain?) that you tried?

Comment: I've tired 6 9 12 13 16 19 21 24. They all showed me

Comment: How long did it take to finish that? If it's too quick (less than 3 seconds) then it might not be reliable. Can you try N=10 and N=100?

Comment: The longest 24 took 124160ns. I will try N= 100 and N 10 soon. Thx. And could u plz tell me why it might not be reliable?

Comment: Because running time might include system initialization and other random stuff happening in your system. In this case you can try to find N that gives you about 1 second of running time, then try 2N to see whether it's around 8 seconds. =)

Comment: Yes I also guess that the problem is that the execution time is almost nothing compared to the rest, it takes some time until the vm is ready to execute the program itself.

Answer (score 0):

I can show you that's not O(N) for sure.

the first cycle does one time so it's O(N-2). (you start at the number 2)
the second one does it's O(N-L-1).
the third one does it's O(J-1).

in the end it'l be something like O(N*(N-L-1)*(J-1)).
to simplify i can call it O(N^3).

Correct me if i'm wrong.

bottom-up is a type of dynamic programming, and it does not have a algorithm.
It can run at O(N) or less, or more, it depends on the problem.